# How to solve Java heap space error

Tags: java, heap-memory

I am trying to insert 1.30 GB data through ETL in oracle .But i am getting Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error.This is my Exception Tree

```
Wed Mar 05 12:07:18 IST 2014 Starting data-source : Hua_GPRS_CS5_4.7

Wed Mar 05 12:07:18 IST 2014 Fetching Files @ ./data/huagprs/source

Processing next 20 files from ./data/huagprs/source
Processing file:        D:\workspace\TestHardNess\data\huagprs\source\LEPC18_b00326794.dat_140110.100308_7518.Z
 Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:2694)
at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:203)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:405)
at jayu.ASCIIFormattable.byteArr2TimeStamp(ASCIIFormattable.java:173)
at hua.gprs.HuawieGPRS.getValue(HuawieGPRS.java:122)
at hua.gprs.HuawieGPRS.recordToString(HuawieGPRS.java:37)
at hua.gprs.HuawieGPRS.recordToString(HuawieGPRS.java:60)
at hua.gprs.HuawieGPRS.recordToString(HuawieGPRS.java:47)
at hua.gprs.HuawieGPRS.recordToString(HuawieGPRS.java:60)
at hua.gprs.HuawieGPRS.recordToString(HuawieGPRS.java:30)
at hua.gprs.HuawieGPRSParser.persefile(HuawieGPRSParser.java:123)
at hua.gprs.HuaGPRSFileExecutor.processFile(HuaGPRSFileExecutor.java:16)
at com.etl.FileExecutor.run(FileExecutor.java:166)
at com.etl.JobManager.executeFiles(JobManager.java:113)
at com.etl.JobManager.crawlDir(JobManager.java:196)
at com.etl.JobManager.run(JobManager.java:83)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

eclipse ini configuration

```
-startup
    plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
   --launcher.library
   plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
  -product
  org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
   --launcher.defaultAction
    openFile
   --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
   256M
  -showsplash
  org.eclipse.platform
   --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
   256m
  --launcher.defaultAction
  openFile
  -vmargs
  -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
   -Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
  -Xms40m
  -Xmx512m
```

Comment: Do you have any chance to transfer those data in a stream?

Comment: sorry i did not get u

Comment: Try increasing your Heap space using the -Xms and -Xmx jvm parameters.
Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763079/what-are-the-xms-and-xmx-parameters-when-starting-jvms) question.

Comment: @lucifer you obviously blow your heap by loading all data into the memory. Check your API if it offers you a possibility to send that data not as one big chunk from memory but streamable.

Comment: @TejasKale i am using eclipse ide when i am trying to change -Xmx and -Xmn eclipse is saying that  it cannot create the JVM

Comment: @lucifer What are the values you are using, and what is your system configuration? Remember, you can't have more than 4GB on a 32 bit system.

Comment: @TejasKale i am adding configuration with my post

Comment: @lucifer Wait, that's your eclipse configuration, What parameters is the oracle JVM launched with? Those are the ones you need to tweak.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266077/eclipse-heap-space-out-of-memory-error

Comment: Try ti increase the --launcher.XXMaxPermSize to 512M. Is this a standalone program or run on any Application server, if so you need to increase in application server.

Comment: @TejasKale -Xms40m
  -Xmx512m these two

Comment: @lucifer eclipse.ini dictates the parameters for the Eclipse process, You will have different parameters for your oracle instance. In any case, -Xms is the min heap space that the process is launched with and It can expand upto a maximum of -Xmx. So configure it accordingly.

Comment: Whats the RAM size in your system and what is the available RAM memory ?

Comment: @Jay 4 gb(2.75) usable

Comment: @TejasKale how far i can allocate these two parameters -Xms and -Xmx??

Comment: Don't you have any other 64 bits system with higher RAM to try this ?

Comment: @lucifer Depends completely on your RAM *and* your system architecture. For 32bit systems, the maximum is 4GB.

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase your -Xms and -Xmx parameters. You can use sthg like this;

```
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.0.200.v20090519
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.201.R35x_v20090715.jar
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

Comment: @lucifer as I commented above, Its the oracle DB instance that needs to have more memory, not eclipse.

Comment: Is it a standalone Java program that you run in Eclipse ? If so you need to tune the JVM memory of Eclipse only. If its a code that is executed in a Application server like Weblogic then you need to tune the Weblogic JVM. I think its nothing to do with Oracle DB instance.

Comment: it is a application that is running in eclipse and not in any server.

Comment: You get this error during the file read operation. How does your file read code looks like ? This link could give you some statistics http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428657/reading-text-file-to-string-without-huge-memory-consumption